# objective-c Fbric crashlytics "Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating."

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

trying to install Fabric Crashlytics on my Cordova project

I followed all the steps and installing all rquired steps with building the project , but at the final step i got stuck there without any action

here is my AppDelegate.h

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

@implementation AppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
return YES;
}
@end
```

after I build the project it's stuck there without any action

[image]

^^ this screen waits for 1 minute then it's cahnged to [image]

I checked the info.plist and seems good without any problem
[image]

Comment: are u testing on real device or simulator?

Comment: Recheck all the configuration you made while integrating and make sure to restart Xcode!

Comment: the testing was for simulator , just doing build using ctrl+R

Comment: @Anurag Sharma i checked the integration many times without any effect, i close the xcode , i deleted the fabric files and same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't have support for Cordova based projects. We need to see a build and run of your app with Fabric enabled. I'd recommend a clean, build and run with Fabric enabled on a device to see if that helps.

Comment: I get the same issue in react native. Any help there?

Comment: We don't have support for React Native apps. Likely we're not seeing the build event needed to activate the app in which case a clean, build and run may help.